# How to access someone else's AWS S3 'bucket' with Boto3 and Username?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to download AWS S3 content using Python/Boto3.

A third-party is uploading a data, and I need to download it.
They provided credentials like this:

- Username : `MYUser`
- aws_access_key_id : `SOMEKEY`
- aws_secret_access_key : `SOMEOTHERKEY`

Using a popular Windows 10 app CyberDuck, my 'Username' is added to the application's path settings, `third-party/MYUser/myfolder`

Nothing I'm given here is *my bucket*.

```
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('third-party/MYUser')
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name 'third-party/MYUser': Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('third-party')
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('MYStuff')
NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

From what I've read, `third-party` is the AWS S3 bucket name, but I can't find an explanation for how to access a sub-directory of someone else's bucket.

I'm see `Bucket()` has some *user* parameters. I read elsewhere about *roles*, and *access control lists*. But I'm not finding a simple example.

**How do I access someone else's bucket on AWS S3 given Username?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not actually have directories. Rather, the `Key` (filename) of an object contains the **full path** of the object.

For example, consider this object:

```
s3://my-bucket/invoices/foo.txt
```

- The bucket is `my-bucket`
- The Key of the object is `invoices/foo.txt`

So, you could access the object with:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('my-bucket','invoices/foo.txt')
```

To keep S3 compatible with systems and humans who expect to have folders and directories, it maintains a list of `CommonPrefixes`, which are effectively the same as directories. They are derived from the names between slashes (`/`). So, CyberDuck can give users the ability to navigate through directories.

However, the third-party might have only assigned you enough permission to access your own directory, but not the root directory. In this case, you will need to navigate straight to your directory without clicking through the hierarchy.

A good way to use an alternate set of credentials is to store them as a separate profile:

```
aws configure --profile third-party
```

You will then be prompted for the credentials.

Then, you can use the credentials like this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://third-party/MyUser --profile third-party
aws s3 cp s3://third-party/MyUser/folder/foo.txt .
```

The `--profile` at the end lets you select which credentials to use.

The boto3 equivalent is:

```py
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='third-party')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('THEIR-bucket','MYinvoices/foo.txt')
```

See: [Credentials — Boto 3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Comment: Then 'my bucket' is always the 'account-owner's-bucket'. Haha! :P

Comment: It is the _name_ of the bucket, regardless of who owns it. Amazon S3 bucket names are globally unique.

Comment: All the secondary sources reference *my bucket*, and you have keys. You start thinking, must not be *'my bucket'* if my keys don't work. Now I'm understanding S3 buckets have [users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_identity-management.html#intro-identity-users). You have to go deep to discover my [use case](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/) (and I'm still on the outside as this is the *'my-bucket'* owner's guide).

Comment: To add to your confusion: Users do not own resources. Users are assigned permission to do things to their AWS Account. All resources are owned by the account. Just think of `my-bucket` as `a-bucket` that is owned by a particular account.